# Uncaught exception from servlet javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, ringojs

After I deploy my web app to google app engine servers, all seems fine:

```
99% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
99% Uploading index definitions.

Update completed successfully.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files...
```

However, when trying to test it from the url: `myappname.appspot.com`, i got this common error:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

In the log of my app, this is the error i got:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:451)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I'm new to GAE, so I need to understand how to solve such errors. Thanx in advance.

**P.S:** If that will help, i am deploying a `ringojs` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some limitations on how you can use threads in Java on App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply. What's wrong with my basic application? I just set up the admin app, deploy it to the server and try to get the it's working message on the browser.

Comment: I didn't add any line of code, the code running so far is the one provided by the SDK when setting up new app. So it's the basic code.

Comment: This means there may be a problem in your appengine-web.xml or web.xml files. Some settings may be wrong or missing.

Comment: In a live example, i saw that the directory name and the remote name of the applcation is the same. In my case it's not, could be this the problem ?

Comment: @Malloc this may be a problem with recent versions of ringojs. would you please bring this up on ringojs mailing list or irc... might have to do with recent changes how ringo web apps work (worker threads and how they are managed).

Comment: @oberhamsi I posted on the mailing list, hope get help soon :). By the way, may i upgrade my ringojs version? may be that will help.

Comment: @Malloc what version are you using? I'll try reproduce your problem now. I would have expected 0.7 or 0.8 releases to work but current master not (to be fixed, hopefully)

Comment: @oberhamsi: How to know the version from the command line, i couldn't get it from the readme or github account. Any Way, I have cloned ringojs 1 week ago, so i guess it's the latest master when writing these lines. Please check it with me and get me updated. Thanx for your patience.

Comment: @Malloc i responded on the mailing list